# Displaying LINQ query results in a DataGridView with a DataTable

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, datatable

I have a function which contains a LINQ query and returns the results as a DataTable. I'm having trouble using the returned DataTable to populate a DataGridView. The query should be returning some data, but the table looks to be coming back empty. My function is as follows:

```
public static DataTable GetEmployeeTimesheets(int employeeId)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    using (PTMS_DataEntities entities = new PTMS_DataEntities())
    {
        var timesheets = from timesheet in entities.Timesheets
                         join timesheetTask in entities.Timesheet_Task
                         on timesheet.Id equals timesheetTask.Timesheet_Id
                         join task in entities.Tasks
                         on timesheetTask.Task_Id equals task.Id
                         join project in entities.Projects
                         on task.Project_Id equals project.Id
                         join department in entities.Departments
                         on project.Department_Id equals department.Id
                         where timesheet.Employee_Id == employeeId
                         select new
                         {
                             date = timesheet.Date,
                             taskName = task.Name,
                             projectName = project.Name,
                             projectDesc = project.Description,
                             departmentName = department.Name,
                             taskEstimatedHours = task.Estimated_Hours,
                             timesheetHours = timesheetTask.Hours
                         };

        table.Columns.Add("date");
        table.Columns.Add("taskName");
        table.Columns.Add("projectName");
        table.Columns.Add("projectDesc");
        table.Columns.Add("departmentName");
        table.Columns.Add("taskEstimatedHours");
        table.Columns.Add("timesheetHours");

        foreach (var item in timesheets)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(item.date, item.taskName, item.projectName,
                item.projectDesc, item.departmentName, item.taskEstimatedHours,
                item.timesheetHours);
        }
    }

    return table;
}
```

The code populating the DataGridView is as follows:

```
    TimesheetGrid.DataSource = EmployeeManager.GetEmployeeTimesheets(employeeId);
    TimesheetGrid.DataBind();
```

Am I doing something wrong in the function / LINQ query itself, or am I just not populating the DataGridView correctly?

Comment: "Should be returning some data"? Is it or is it not?

Comment: Can you please debug and tell us if `timesheets` actually has data in it before the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Debug through timesheets to get sql query, and check the results in SSMS.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - It is not returning any data. I stepped through the code and there is no data before the foreach, either.

Comment: I ran the query in SQL Mangement Studio and the query returned results...so I have a feeling the LINQ is wrong or I'm populating the DataTable incorrectly.

Comment: How could you have run this in SQL Management Studio, there is no SQL here.  Download and use linqPad to debug.